# run groovy script from groovy with command line arguments

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I need to run groovy script file from another groovy, 
and get the console output.
I've tried to use GroovyScriptEngine, 
but the problem is that I need to pass command line arguments to the script
also I didn't succeed to get the console output

Thanks!!!
Barb

Answer (score 0):

One slightly cheese way (sorry I'd give you a better example but I'm heading out soon) -

```
            def cmdLine = "some Command"
    String logFileErr = "logfile.log"
    String logFileStd = "stdout"
    def fose = new FileOutputStream(logFileErr)
    def foss = new FileOutputStream(logFileStd)
    Process proc = cmdLine.execute()
    fose << proc.in
    fose << proc.err
    foss << proc.out
    proc.waitFor()
```

This uses an output stream to consume both the stdout and stderr.  You could do something with those inputs other than stream them to a file if you'd like (or parse the output files and use that).